# Regex to not allow

Tags: javascript, php, regex, email

I need a customized condition to test users input. I'm using Regex to check if the user's input is either a string of only numbers or a valid email address.

The current Regex is as below and has effectively weeded out most wrong addresses:

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

However, there are still a few that misses the shoot out:

1. Arabic characters
2. wwww. (user put wwww.someone@hotmail.com rather than the correct someone@hotmail.com)
3. wrong spellings of .com such as .cpm, cum, xom, ccom, cim

I'm planning to add a test to check if the input has 1-3, but am a bit clueless as to how that can be achieved. Any advice?

Comment: Why would `wwww.someone@hotmail.com` be an invalid e-mail address?

Comment: It could. But most of the time it's invalid and the person meant someone@hotmail.com. For those that do have www. in their email addresses, I don't care since it's such a small fraction compared to those who use it wrongly.

Comment: Personally, I'd just use `\S+@\S\.\S+` and then **send an actual e-mail**. That's the *only* way you're going to be able to tell if a given e-mail address is real or not.

Comment: @AmalMurali you forgot a `+` after the second `\S`. And with the new tlds I guess something like `name@mailcomp`, without any dot in the domain name is not unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

There's no proper "fits them all" solution, but if you exclude uncommon and really awkward things (like embedded quotes), it's possible to simplify such an regular expression (ignore casing):

```
^[a-z](?:[\.+\-]?\w+)*@[a-z]+(?:[\.\-]?\w+)*$
```

This expression should match pretty much all common email formats.

Specifically, it will enforce the following restrictions:

- Start with a letter.
- Local part might include `.`, `+`, and `-`, but they're not allowed to follow each other multiple times.
- Local part has to end with an alphanumeric character.
- The domain name has to start with an alphanumeric character.
- The domain name might include `.` or `-`, but they aren't allowed to be the last character.

Note that this won't verify the TLD of the email address, since you're never able to really include all of them (and new ones keep getting added on a quite regular basis).

Instead use a two-step verification process, if it's really important for the user to provide a valid email address: Once signed up or registered, send an email with a confirmation link to mark the email address as valid/working.

Comment: Hi thanks Mario. But I don't think this can exclude wrong spellings of .com such as .cpm, cum, xom, ccom, cim. Do you have advice for this part? Thanks!

Comment: @user3192948: just have the users fill in the email twice and compare them. Users making the same typo twice is unlikely. Furthermore, the only truly reliable way to make sure that only real email addresses are stored in your database is to send a confirmation mail with a conformation link. I mean, vladimir.poetin@whitehouse.gov will pass all checks, but is very likely a fake address.

Comment: Hi Frank, I have to think from a business pov as well. Signup rate falls by 40% when you ask people to fill in the email address twice, and I cannot reduce my signup by 40% just to weed out a couple of fake email addresses. Really what I'm looking for is a way to spot .cpm, .cum and such and give a warning msg.

Comment: @user3192948 40%? Where did you get that number from? Even then I think that has more to do with people thinking about potentially unwanted spam after giving away an email address - not just having to confirm some text field once.

Comment: From using that method earlier and tested over 50,000 visitors.

Comment: That's really odd. But at the same time you're mixing concepts here: Avoid typos vs. avoid intentionally wrong addresses. Which one is more important?